# How do I generate a match for a regex?

Tags: command-line, bash, regex

Is there a tool out there that would take in a regex argument and spit out a valid combination? It should **make a string that matches the regex.**

For example:

- `clear`

  - `clear`
- `ls (-[al]{2}|-a -l|-l -a)`

  - `ls -al`,
  - or `ls -a -l`

Comment: I want it to *make* a valid expression (so that it matches the regex), not find it in a document.

Answer (score 2):

Pick any of the methods from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492716/2072269), and use Python to run it. For example:

```
$ python -c 'import rstr; print(rstr.xeger("ls (-[al]{2}|-a -l|-l -a)"))'
ls -a -l
```

You might have to `pip install` the rstr module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any tool that does what you want out of the box - in fact, I'd be surprised if there were - what should it do with expressions that contain wildcards (such as `.*` for example - would you expect it to output every possible character?)

Probably the closest would be some kind of *regular expression deparser* that would generate a parse tree for you, that you would then need to traverse from root to leaf (backing up as necessary if you want to reach every possible leaf node). Something like perl's [YAPE::Regex](http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-4.00/Regex.pm) module for example - in fact you might be able to base your solution on the [YAPE::Regex::explain](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAPE-Regex-Explain/Explain.pm) extension:

```
$ printf '(-[al]{2}|-a -l|-l -a)' | 
    perl -MYAPE::Regex::Explain -ne 'print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new($_)->explain'
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:(-[al]{2}|-a -l|-l -a))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [al]{2}                  any character of: 'a', 'l' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -a -l                    '-a -l'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -l -a                    '-l -a'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(I don't know why it wraps the expression in an additional `(?:...)` non-capturing group).

Unfortunately the module doesn't seem to be available from the Ubuntu repositories, but you should be able to install it via CPAN.